# Insert X or Y for Column A, B, C, D

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

What I need is an X placed if the start range (A1:A) equals range (E1:K1) until range (B1:B). Then the same for C and D in the same row. So Y should take place of X if true. What I have tried is `=IF(AND($A1<=E$1,$B1>=E$1),"X","")` but I cant seem to get it to work for both sets.[image]

Comment: Can you illustrate with image or example?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: one formula will not work for both you need two.

Comment: `=IF(AND($C1<=E$1,$D1>=E$1),"Y","")` should be the formula for the Y row first cell and then copy it over.

Comment: ah you want both X & Y in the same row. Sorry your image misled me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the formula I put in as per the requirement.
The trick was that I split it into two `IF` function calls one inside the other, there by allowing opportunity for our third value of "".

[image]